# Migration Mismatch of entities in the document and Volume Check Failed

Tags: magento2.3, magento2-migration-tool

migration **Map step after** below error showing

> [2019-03-15 08:59:48][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document:
>   catalog_product_website Source: **7821** Destination: **7758**
>
> `Volume Check failed`

[image]

Comment: Have you already solved this problem? I'm also stuck on this one, except here all my destination is 0

Comment: no..... @Umizoomi